# Accessing Stacked SVG's :hover or ON MouseEnter

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I have a stack of SVG circles that show a student their progress in a class. There are 3 distinct metrics:

1. Expected Progress - How much of the course you should have completed, by time, shown as a percent
2. Quality of work - Your typical grade "80%", you've gotten 8 of 10 questions correct
3. Final Grade - As a percent. A mix of Quality of work over time. If
   time is up and you're not done, even if you have a 100% quality
   score, your final score is very low.

I'm looking to describe those metrics in a "callout" but am unable to access all but the top most svg circle. CSS doesn't access the other circles... Any ideas?: https://codepen.io/lucasOnCodePen/pen/gxjvjo

CSS:

```
circle.final:hover, circle.completed:hover, circle.expected:hover {
   stroke-width: 25;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var svgCircles = $(".circle svg");
    svgCircles.each(function() {
    var realPercent = $(this).data("percent") / 100;
    var offSet = 370 - 370 * realPercent;
    $(this).addClass("filled");
    $(this).css("stroke-dashoffset", offSet);
   });
});
```

I'm also very open to other ideas about the presentation. The metrics are wonky, but there isn't much I can do about that outside of just explain them to the user.

Answer (score 1):

CSS can access every circles, not only the top one. The problem is `z-index`. Even if visually circles (both `<svg>` and `<circle>`) don't cover each other fully, they are still equal-sized square blocks. That means that `:hover` fires only for circle with biggest `z-index`.

Perhaps, [canvas](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/) might be better solution at this situation. But it is also requires much more js.